# Doubt regarding negative exponentiation

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have a doubt about evaulation of $(-1)^{1/3}$ and $(-1)^{1/2}$. Can someone point out the error in the following steps?
$$(-1)^{1/3} = ((-1)^2)^{1/6} = 1^{1/6} = 1$$

Similarly we get, $i = (-1)^{1/2} = 1$.

Is this error because of use of only positive numbers as a base? If yes, then how do I proceed to evaluate $(-1)^{1/3}$ and get $-1$ as my real solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is an error to assume that $(x^a)^b=x^{ab}$ is valid even when $x$ is negative. Defining $x^a=e^{a\ln x},$ (where $\ln$ is the principal value of the log function) a proof of this result for positive $x$ might proceed as
$$
(x^a)^b=e^{b\ln (e^{a \ln x})}=e^{ab \ln x}=x^{ab}.
$$
If $x<0$ this proof fails in the step where we assume $\ln (e^{a \ln x})=a\ln x.$ This step fails because $e^x$ is function that takes many values to a single value, and so $\ln y$ fails in general to invert $e^x.$

Comment: Thanks, your explanation seems good. But then  ,how do I proceed to evaluate (-1)^1/3 and (-1)^2/3 to -1 and 1 as real solutions respectively?

Comment: $-1$ has three complex cube roots, one of them is $-1$. The "standard" way to evaluate $(-1)^{1/3}$ called the principal value is actually not $-1$, but one of the other complex roots. That said, you can tweak the conventions to get basically any one of the three roots you want to get.